# one to one transaction db to data warehouse dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensions

I have a situation where we have vehicle options and options packs tables in transaction db. now we want to move data to data warehouse.
transaction DB example.

[image]

I am generating surrogate keys(pk) based on all options.

Can you please suggest some ways how to move data in data warehouse?

I am suggesting dim map which will keep only optionpacks and option's surrogate keys, one separate dim for options only

Comment: Your question is very broad. You should specify your question a little bit.

Comment: basically there are two tables. 1 options --> that includes all options Ids and desc. 2- optionpack table that include optionID (from options table) and OptionPackID. I added above information as I am importing as one data in stage table.  Thanks.

Comment: Are asking how to move the data from source to target (i.e. this is an ETL question) or are you asking how to model this data in a dimensional model? In either case you are going to need to provide a lot more information in order for anyone to be able to help you e.g. table structures, example data, example outcome, etc